# How to use this Logger to log a specific class of data type

Tags: c++, logging

I'm new to c++ and I'm doing a class project(CMU 15-445 https://github.com/cmu-db/bustub) und debugging.
But I don't know how to use this logger.

from **logger.h** file, **LOG_INFO** is so defined:

```
#ifdef LOG_INFO_ENABLED
#undef LOG_INFO_ENABLED
#endif
#if LOG_LEVEL <= LOG_LEVEL_INFO
#define LOG_INFO_ENABLED
// #pragma message("LOG_INFO was enabled.")
#define LOG_INFO(...)                                                      \
  OutputLogHeader(__SHORT_FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, LOG_LEVEL_INFO); \
  ::fprintf(LOG_OUTPUT_STREAM, __VA_ARGS__);                               \
  fprintf(LOG_OUTPUT_STREAM, "\n");                                        \
  ::fflush(stdout)
#else
#define LOG_INFO(...) ((void)0)
#endif
```

I know that LOG_INFO("xxx") can print out xxx, but I want to print a value of type <Generic_Key>,
in **generic_key.h**

```
  // NOTE: for test purpose only
  // interpret the first 8 bytes as int64_t from data vector
  inline int64_t ToString() const { return *reinterpret_cast<int64_t *>(const_cast<char *>(data_)); }

  // NOTE: for test purpose only
  // interpret the first 8 bytes as int64_t from data vector
  friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const GenericKey &key) {
    os << key.ToString();
    return os;
  }
```

So if I want to print  `The key is inserted.`and key is type of GenricKey.
I've tried something like LOG_INFO("The key" << key << "is inserted"); but it was wrong.
Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Looking at the macro, the arguments are passed to fprintf, so you need to look at a [reference for fprintf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) to see what is acceptable (too long to explain here). But `fprintf` is a C function, so it's not going to be able to print any C++ objects.

Comment: what do you mean by `value of type`? do you want to stringinize class name or do you want to print some `Generic_Key::value`?

Comment: in relation to @john: if you want to use `friend std::ostream &operator<<` this with fprintf, i suggest to use translation method from any object to `const char *` with `std::stringstream` but it's not elegant.

Comment: @KrzysztofMochocki I want to print some Generic_Key::value, its a class wrapping int64_t, I think.

Comment: @john I looked the reference but still have no idea how to do it. As they gave this operater<< function, I think there is an easy way to use it.

Comment: @happyv You should follow Kryzysztof's suggestion. i.e. `std::ostringstream buffer; buffer << "The key" << key << "is inserted"; LOG_INFO("%s", buffer.str().c_str());`

Comment: @john Thank you guys, it works!